# Dismissing messages

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed

A few days ago, we got yellow messages like "please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved". When you clicked on such a message, it disappeared. With the new style (red), this isn't possible anymore. Some messages, like "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds." have a cross on the right to dismiss it.

I got used to dismissing by clicking and found it way easier than the cross we now have. Is there a good reason for removing the click-to-dismiss feature? If not, can that feature please return? Otherwise: Why haven't all the messages a cross? Can they all have one if there is no good reason?

Comment: Agreed, +1.  It was annoying enough to have that stupid yellow box pop up in the first place, but you could at least dismiss it easily.  Now you have to click the X, which is even more of a hassle.  I really don't care how many votes I have left that day, or how many other votes it still takes to close a question, etc.  I want the system to just do it.  I can see the number of close votes in parenthesis behind "close".

Comment: I just flagged three vandalous posts as *not welcome in our community*. Each time the new red popup appeared and I had to move the mouse just right over the little X instead of the whole box. This is seriously demotivational in spending my volunteer time to help clean up this site. There shouldn't be a popup at all, let alone one where I have to align the mouse just right to get rid of. Argh.

Comment: Sorry about that. What you see now is just a first step in a series of improvements to errors and notifications that we are planning to roll out over the next week or so. The current behaviour for these notifications did end up super-annoying, and we're planning on fixing that up in the next stages.

Comment: Very well. Please let us know when you're finished so that we can have this discussion again with the new notifications.

Comment: @CamilStaps that is [meta-tag:status-declined]. Telling you when updates happen is the most assured way to get bug reports :)

Comment: I'm sure everyone will notice these either way. :)

Comment: @CamilStaps Was joking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These notification messages should now disappear on their own without any clicking required at all.

Comment: The "you can't vote for your own post" still has a cross. (just trying!)

Comment: And the "Thanks, we'll take a look at it!" after flagging a question still has it too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest we get rid of these annoying popups altogether.  There were a minor hassle before, but have now become a more significant aggrevation.  Why do I really need to know how many more votes it will take to close a question, especially when the total votes is already shown immediately after "close"?  This has now raised the level of flagging for moderator attention enough so now you have to think about whether you really want to bother.

There are some of us that really dislike using the mouse, and this new scheme has increased the annoyance level significantly.  It's time the whole thing go away.

Comment: What about the pop-ups "Don't forget you can accept this answer...", "Please consider adding a comment..."? I consider those to be useful, especially for new users. Perhaps for those messages make a pop-up (in the old style) for inexperienced users?

Comment: If it is not worth your time to click through the menu for flagging a moderator it is probably not work flagging me :)

Comment: @Kortuk: See the ones I flagged earlier today.  I think you'd agree they were worth flagging.  I even downvoted them just so I could also vote to delete them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It was meant to be a joke mostly, that is why I put the :) so that people realize my tone, or at least annoying faces is the best way I have found to do so.