# Messages still have crosses

Tags: bug, status-completed

I earlier asked [Dismissing messages](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2675/17592), on which Anna Lear [answered](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2685/17592) and I commented on that answer. I assume that I don't get a reply because [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) is included, that's why I ask this new question.

Anna Lear:

> These notification messages should now disappear on their own without any clicking required at all.

However, here is a list of messages that still have crosses to close them:

- You can accept this answer in x minutes
- You can't vote for your own post
- Thanks, we'll take a look at it (after flagging)

Can this be fixed? As Olin Lathrop [points out](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/dismissing-messages#comment4442_2675) this is very annoying behaviour.

Comment: You probably did not get a response because she gets ~100s of inbox notifications when she logs in. Probably accidental oversight.

Comment: Yes, and I respect that! It wasn't meant as a reproach, sorry for that.

Comment: I did not think you meant it that way, just explaining, pinging community managers is not always the best way to get a response as they likely get hundreds. We ping them randomly in the TL just to keep them on their toes.

Comment: Okay. What happens to this question now? Is someone working on it?

Comment: They can track tags cross site, so they will see this bug and respond. Plausibly they will just update it when they fix it / tell you if they wont or tell you status planned if the result is a ways off.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'll pass this on. :)

Comment: These are all definitely on the list to fix.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell I see things have changed. The messages I've seen up to now disappear on their own, thanks! I see some irregularities though. Are you done already or am I just too quick with shouting again? ;-)

Comment: You may want to give us a couple of more days, but fixes went out today for a lot of them.

Comment: Sorry, I should also add that we decided to leave the crosses, but make errors click to close.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell thanks for all the improvements! One question: some messages are blue, others are red. What's the system behind that?

Comment: Basically we are reserving red for errors only.  There are places where we couldn't differentiate for technical reasons - and places we're still working on -  but looking forward, red should always mean error

Comment: @JeremyTunnell that's clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JeremyTunnell sorry to bother you again, but the "Thanks, we'll take a look at it"-message after flagging a post is red. Is that meant this way? Because I wouldn't see it as an error.

Comment: We've still got a few stray ones. It's on the list, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeremy said in the comments, these error messages still have Xs to dismiss; but they also can be closed by clicking them (as before), and now fade away after a set period of time.

Think some of the colors may still be being tweaked though.